# MySQL for Visual studio 1.2.7 setup wizard ended prematurely

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, edmx

Created a proj from VS2013 installed mysql plugin 1.1.1, can update. But after I transferred to VS2017, it wont update Model from Database on edmx file. So I am installing mysql plugin 1.2.7 but i get this error..

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from the MySQL Windows Experience Team

I've identified that the installation is rolling back whenever it tries to execute the command "devenv /updateconfiguration /log", which is the last step of the installation. This command signals Visual Studio to reload the extensions, including the MySQL for Visual Studio plugin, however for some strange reason (probably due to one of the recent VS updates) execution of said command is failing.

The current workaround is to remove the execution of the failing command from the MSI and after installation of the plugin proceed to execute the command manually. Steps to achieve that are as follows:

1. Download and install Orca. Orca is a light Windows Installer Development tool that allows to edit MSIs.
2. In Windows explorer, right click the MySQL for Visual Studio MSI file and select "Edit with Orca".
3. Click the "InstallExecuteSequence" item located under the "Tables" section on the left side of the window.
4. If you're trying to install in VS Community right click the "SetVS15Setup_Custom" action and select "Drop Row" option. Do the same for "VS15Setup_Custom". Similar elements exist for VS Professional/Enterprise.
5. Save changes and retry installation of MySQL for Visual Studio.
6. Once installation completes, open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017". It can be found in VS 2017's start menu folder.
7. In the command prompt execute the command "devenv /updateconfiguration /log" and wait for it to complete.

I hope that the steps provided are of help.

Credit goes to: 
Marco Barnabò (for reporting the bug) & 
Jose Maria Ramirez (for solving the issue)

The solution was obtained from the mySQL forums:
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,660549,661819#msg-661819