# MySQL for Visual Studio installer ended prematurely

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I tried to install MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9 but the program shows a screen and says that it ended prematurely.

I tried this answer but it didn't work: [MySQL for Visual studio 1.2.7 setup wizard ended prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512443/mysql-for-visual-studio-1-2-7-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely)

Thanks.

Edit: I include an image.
[Installer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc2T1.jpg)

Also a Log: https://mega.nz/file/PzoiVJqR#gdULetgSQlBfZ8uB5ZeS9-UjPW83GLnCR8yXF0bgCIo

Comment: Hi, please could you provide either a log file or an error code and reproducible steps? This would allow us to better help you.

Comment: I include an image

Comment: And also I include a log